# c++ map insert fails to compile when inserting an object that contains a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, stdmap

I am having trouble (compile time, gcc 17) inserting an object in an std::map which contains a unique_ptr. If I use a regular pointer it compiles (if I take the copy constructor out!).
Here is the struct containing a unique_ptr. With a ctor, copy ctor, etc, with std::move semantics everywhere. Has anyone seen this issue before?

```
#include <utility>      // std::pair, std::make_pair
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <map>
#include <memory>

struct Struct1
{
    Struct1(std::unique_ptr<std::string> pStr)
        : pStr_(std::move(pStr)){}
   ~Struct1(){}
    Struct1(Struct1& other)
        : pStr_(std::move(other.pStr_)){}
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> pStr_;
};
```

Here is the main. Anything I try I get a "no matching function" for insert

```
int main () {
    std::string s("key");
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> pStr = std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello");

    std::map<std::string, Struct1>list;
    Struct1 ste(std::move(pStr));
    std::pair<std::string, Struct1> p(s,ste); // copy into a pair
    // std::pair<std::string, Struct1> p(s,std::move(ste)); // copy into a pair
    // auto p = std::make_pair(s, std::move(ste));
    // auto p = std::make_pair(s, ste);
    // list.insert(std::move(p));
    list.insert(p);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
Struct1(Struct1& other)
```

As per language standard, it's the copy constructor; what you did here (by typo or on purpose, I don't know) is a `auto_ptr`-style neither-move-nor-copy-semantics. Though with that done, the copy assignment is auto-generated, while the move operations are completely removed (unless defined manually).

Didn't you want that instead?

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <string>      
#include <iostream>    
#include <map>
#include <memory>

struct Struct1
{
    Struct1(std::unique_ptr<std::string> pStr)
        : pStr_(std::move(pStr)){}
   ~Struct1(){}
    Struct1(Struct1&& other) //double! ampersand
        : pStr_(std::move(other.pStr_)){}
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> pStr_;
};

int main () {
    std::string s("key");
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> pStr = std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello");

    std::map<std::string, Struct1>list;
    Struct1 ste(std::move(pStr));
    std::pair<std::string, Struct1> p{s,std::move(ste)}; //note the move 
    list.insert(std::move(p)); //and here
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fs44j69ja

Comment: Seems like it needs move ctor for insert and if there is a copy ctor (which I need for some other purpose) it wants to use the copy ctor for insert. If I mention the default move ctor then it seem to work `Struct1(Struct1&& other) = default;`
For the pair though, it seems like it could use either the copy ctor or the move ctor depending on the signature.

Answer (score 0):

When you have opt into `struct`s, you can avoid creating your own constructor unless it's really needed. Instead, `Struct1` could simply be:

```cpp
struct Struct1
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> pStr_;
};
```

All the copy/move constructors and assignment operators will be generated automatically if possible. However, since you have a `unique_ptr` in the struct, who does not have a copy constructor or assignment operator, those will not be generated for you, which you don't need them in your case anyways.

---

Now the rest will be pretty simply, as long you remember to call `move` on your objects properly:

```cpp
std::string s("key");
std::map<std::string, Struct1> list;

// prefer using `auto` when the type can already be deduced from `make_unique`
auto pStr = std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello");

// You must move `pStr` to construct `ste` since `pStr` is a `unique_ptr`.
// Also note you are using bracket `{}`, instead of parentheses `()` to create `Struct1`
Struct1 ste{std::move(pStr)};
// With C++20, parentheses is also allowed:
Struct1 ste(std::move(pStr));

// Similarly, you must move `ste` since it contents a `unique_ptr` in it
// Also note the type of the pair, the Key must be `const`
std::pair<const std::string, Struct1> p(s, std::move(ste));

// Once again, you must move `p` for the same reason
list.insert(std::move(p));
```

---

Moreover, there are two steps that can be shortened:

```cpp
std::string s("key");
std::map<std::string, Struct1> list;

// You can create `ste` directly without creating `pStr` first.
// This will also reduce the chance for accidentally using `pStr` again later.
Struct1 ste{std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello")};

// You can then simply emplace `ste` into `list`, or use the subscript operator`[]` without creating the `pair` first
list.emplace(s, std::move(ste));
// or
list[s] = std::move(ste);
```

---

You can even reduce your code more aggressively:

```cpp
std::string s("key");
std::map<std::string, Struct1> list;

list[s] = {std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello")};
// or since C++20
list.emplace(s, std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello"));
```

Comment: You are correct I don't need any explicit ctor for this example but, in my real code I have a need for a copy ctor so when that is in there then the move ctor needs to also be there otherwise the insert would try to use the copy ctor it seems.